# Socket.io won't connect with next.js environment variable

Tags: socket.io, next.js

I have a working environment variable setup, but socketio won't connect with it

in .env.local, I have:

```
HOST=http://localhost:8080
```

then in index.js::

```
console.log(process.env.HOST)    
const socket = io(process.env.HOST)
```

it prints localhost, but won't connect. I've also tried wrapping the link in quotation marks, but that does not work.

Only this configuration works

```
const socket = io('https://localhost:8080')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use that code in the client side code? If so, that is the problem:

By default, nextjs makes environment variables only available in the server side environment (So you can't accidentally expose secrets to the client).
In order to expose certain variables to the client, you have to prefix them with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` like so:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST=http://localhost:8080
```

and

```
console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST)    
const socket = io(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST)
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Could you explain why I needed that? const socket = io(...) was in the javascript, which made me think that it was within the node.js environment and not part of the browser side.

Comment: Although nextjs renders pages on the server, it will "hydrate" the app on the client in order to give the page interactivity. It means that your react code runs first on the server, then on the client. Certain things like data-fetching in "getStaticProps" or API routes run only on the server, so you can use secret environment variables there safely without prefixing them. Since nextjs makes you have server and client code in the same files, forcing you to prefix public variables helps to keep you from accidentally exposing secrets to the client.